R strptime returning NA
I am trying to do a format change, for that I am using striptime()
If I pass the string as I want it works OK
> strptime("   31/12/2015   ", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "2015-12-31 -03"

but the date comes from an excel fil, and I am using library(readxl)
I have tryed with..
> Estadistica[1,1][[1]]
[1] "   30/11/2015   "

> unlist( Estadistica[1,1])
                   
"   30/11/2015   " 

but I always get NA, can't find what is the rigth way to pass the parameter.
eg:
> strptime(Estadistica[1,1][[1]], format = "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] NA

Thanks!

Share a sample of your data dput(Estadistica)

It's likely there are some invisible non-ASCII characters. I would try to use textclean::replace_non_ascii() remove those characters.
library(textclean)
strptime(replace_non_ascii(Estadistica[1,1][[1]]), format = "%d/%m/%Y")

If this does not work, you may have other problems, and I will delete my answer.
